# R: What is the difference between these two plots?

Tags: r, 3d, plotly, data-visualization

I am using the R programming language. I am following this tutorial over here: https://plotly.com/r/3d-surface-plots/

Over here, I have generated some random data and made two plots:

```
library(plotly)

set.seed(123)

#generate data
a = rnorm(100,10,10)
b = rnorm(100,5,5)
c = rnorm(100,5,10)
d = data.frame(a,b,c)

#plot 1
fig1 <- plot_ly(z = ~as.matrix(d))
fig1 <- fig %>% add_surface()

#view plot 1
fig1

#plot 2

fig2 = plot_ly() %>% 
  add_trace(data = d,  x=d$a, y=d$b, z=d$c, type="mesh3d" ) 

#view plot 2
fig2
```

[image]

Can someone please explain why these two plots are different and what is the difference between both of these plots?

Thanks

Comment: Look at the scales.  In figure 1 you are plotting 100 rows (0 to 100 for y) of 3 values  where each column is a value of x (0, 1 and 2).  Figure 2 is 100 points plotted on a surface.  I believe figure is the desired method.

Comment: thank you for your reply! I am not sure I understood ....